Finite Fourier Transform of Fourth Derivative
Sneddon's "Fourier Transforms" shows
$$F_s \frac{∂^4 y}{∂x^4 }=\left(\frac{nπ}{L}\right)^4 F_s (y) $$
where $\frac{∂^2 y(0,t)}{∂x^2 }=\frac{∂^2 y(L,t)}{∂x^2}=0$.
But when I derive the transform using repeated integration by parts, I get
$$\begin{align}
F_s \frac{∂^4 y(x,t)}{∂x^4 }=&
-\frac{nπ}{L}&& \left[\cos(nπ)  \frac{∂^2 y(L,t)}{∂x^2}-\frac{∂^2 y(0,t)}{∂x^2}\right]\\
&+\left(\frac{nπ}{L}\right)^3 &&\left[\cos(nπ)y(L,t)-y(0,t)\right]\\
&+\left(\frac{nπ}{L}\right)^4 &&F_s (y(x,t)).
\end{align}$$
Therefore,
$\frac{∂^2 y(L,t)}{∂x^2}$ and $\frac{∂^2 y(0,t)}{∂x^2}$
appear, which is consistent with Sneddon
but
$y(L,t)$ and $y(0,t)$
also appear.
Have I missed something?

you'll have introduce the symbols you're using here – what are y and x, L and n? Am I right to assume $F_s$ is the Fourier transform operator?

This looks like a Fourier perspective of PDE. Do you have additional boundary conditions that are imposed? Your solution would match Sneddon's when $y(0,t)=y(L,t)=0$, in addition to the second derivative of the ends being zero.
